# Flux - Scalar Multiplication in Integral?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, vectors, vector-fields, calculus

No textbook and website seems to answer this so here is my question:
When we have a scalar flux: I understand that you take the scalar product of the vectors. And I understand the need for using an integral if the flux density is different from place to place. But flux is defined as the integral of flux density scalar multiplied with dA. 
Looking at Magnetic Flux in particular, how can an integral use a scalar product. Is it just "normal" integration or is there anything special done when the integration variable is scalar multiplied with the integrated function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The integration variable is the surface **vector**: flux is an oriented thing. It is the "normal" integration of the scalar product of the field and the surface vector:
$$\Phi=\iint_S \vec{B}\cdot\vec{\mathrm dS}$$

Or, if $\vec{n}$ is the normal to the surface at the point of integration:
$$\Phi=\iint_S \vec{B}\cdot\vec{n}\ \mathrm dS$$

Comment: So if I have a function B(x,y). Lets make it simple and say B(x) = 5x + 2y. I will just do a Surface Integral without any special integration method. I get the writing, but if you could show an example?

Comment: A scalar function won't do. You compute the flux of a _vector_ function.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \mathbf{B} \cdot \,d\mathbf{A} $$ just means $$ \int B\,dA\,\cos\theta. $$ $d\mathbf{A}$ points in the direction perpendicular to the surface, so if this is in the $xy$ plane, it'll be in $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$. 
I.e. your usual integration over the area ("integrand") weighted by a factor of $\cos\theta$. $\theta$ is the angle with the $z$ axis.

Keeping it in vector notation is just nice, clear an concise. To actually do the calculation you'll have to expand it out so that you can implement the limits of the integral.

For exmaple if your $dA$ is $dx\,dy$, then $\mathbf{B}\cdot\,d\mathbf{A} = B_z(x,y)\,dx\,dy$, so that you can integrate over $x$ and $y$ as usual. But if $dA$ is $\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi$, then $\mathbf{B}\cdot\,d\mathbf{A} = B_z(\rho,\theta)\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi$ and you integrate over $\rho$ and $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This diagram shows part of a surface cut up into small elements (shaded pink) of area $dA$.
The normal to the area is the vector $\vec {dA}$ and is of magnitude $dA$.
What is required is the projection of the magnetic field $\vec B$ onto the vector $\vec{dA}$ which is $B_\bot = B \cos \phi$  in the diagram.

To do this the dot product is taken $\vec B \cdot \vec {dA}$ and this is the magnetic flux through the surface element.

The process is then repeated over the whole surface $S$.

$\displaystyle \Phi = \iint_S \vec B \cdot \vec {dA}$